# Wix: MSI failing: Error 3: -2147287038

Tags: .net, wix, windows-8.1, custom-action

I was doing some changes to an existing installer in Wix, and I needed to enable .Net 3.5 on Windows 8. 
This can easily done with the comand "dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /NoRestart". (Windows 8 has .Net35 installed bue is disabled)

So I was doing a simple Installer to add to my Bootstrapper that would run this command. 
The code is below (pastebin):

[WIX CODE](http://pastebin.com/2XpdUA1x)

The problem is that the setup keeps failing when installing... log is below (in pastebin, it is quite extense):

[SETUP LOG](http://pastebin.com/F0mMbsMn)

Google didn't show much, tried some custom UI, running as Admin (I already am Administrator)

I'm testing this on a VM with windows 8.1, running the setupo from the Desktop. Also I'm using Wix 3.8 with Visual Studio 2012

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that really a verbose log? There's nothing in there indicating that it even attempted to run dism.exe, no custom action info, nothing.

Comment: P.S. line 393 MSI (s) (04:D4) [17:20:10:936]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REMOVE property. Its value is 'ALL'. which seems to indicate you have posted a failing uninstall log.

Comment: Yes, it is a verbose log. You're right, the customaction is not being run, at least not apparently.
I think that REMOVE property is due to a failed Install, as a rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your MSI file is missing a Component table, it's not running properly and this issue is nothing to do with dism.exe. The log shows error 2205 on the Component table.